# Showing $(A,d)$ and $(M,d)$ have the same completion if $A$ is dense in $M$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I believe the source of my confusion for this problem has been a mix of overthinking and trying to make sense of poorly formulated arguments. Nonetheless, here is what I have come up with:

> If $A$ is a dense subset of a metric space $(M,d)$, show that $(A,d)$ and $(M,d$) have the same completion *isometrically*. $[$Hint: if $\hat{M}$ is the completion for $M$, then $A$ is dense in $\hat{M}$. Why?$]$

---

Given that $A$ is dense in $M$ we know that $M = \overline{A}$. Therefore, by using the given hint, if $\hat{M}$ is the completion of $M$ then there exists an isometry (which we know to be continuous) $i: M \to \hat{M}$. But, since $M = \overline{A}$ we have that $i: \overline{A} \to \hat{M}$. Therefore, $$\overline{i(\overline{A}}) \stackrel{\mathrm{continuity}}{=} \overline{i(A)}  = \hat{M}.$$
Which would imply that $(M,d)$ and $(A,d)$ have the same completion since $\overline{i(M)} = \hat{M}$ by definition of $(\hat{M},\hat{d})$ being the completion of $(M,d)$.

Is this correct?

---

*Remarks:*

$\bullet$ The definition I am using for a completion of a metric space is as follows: $(\hat{M},\hat{d})$ is a completion for $(M,d)$ $\iff$:

$i)$ $(\hat{M},\hat{d})$ is complete

$ii)$ $(M,d)$ is isometric to a dense subset of $(\hat{M},\hat{d})$ $($ *i.e.*, $\exists$ $i: M \to \hat{M}$ such that $d(x,y) = \hat{d}(i(x),i(y)$ and $\overline{i(M)} = \hat{M}$).

$\bullet$ In my textbook, there is a remark that stood out to me: *informally, condition $ii)$ says that we may regard $M$ as an actual subset of $\hat{M}$, that $\hat{d}$ restricted to $M \times M$ is precisely $d$, and that $M$ is dense in $\hat{M}$.* I believe this serves as a good supplement to my argument above as this would satisfy the hint, if i'm correct, in that $A$ is dense in $\hat{M}$?

Any criticism is welcome.

Comment: Yes. If you think of $M$ as a subset of $\hat M$ by identifying it with $i[M]$, then every open set in $\hat M$ meets $M$ in a relatively open subset of $M$, which in turn meets $M$’s dense subset $A$, so $A$ is dense in $\hat M$. A more formal argument just uses the isometry $i$ to go back and forth between $M$ and $A$ on the one hand and $\hat M$ and $i[A]$ on the other.

Comment: Thats great to hear. I will take a look at proving this by providing this more formal argument. Thanks, Bryan! @BrianM.Scott

Comment: You’re welcome!